# Is it possible to setup a macro or batch file for a program that does not support it?

Tags: windows-7, batch, macros, shell-script

I have to do a time consuming and repetitive process at work on a custom program that was built in-house.It has no native support for macros, batch commands, shell scripts or really anything useful.

Is there some way to "force" it to work with some sort of external command?

I'd love to set some parameters in a file and let it run in the background instead of messing with it, waiting and then messing with it again.

Comment: At that point, you are looking at tools like AutoHotKey or scripts that automate clicks. Neither approach is as reliable or as robust as automation features like macro's or script files, but thats about all you are left with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the OS. Assuming Windows, there are many "UI automation" tools, the most common probably being AutoIt and AutoHotkey. They mainly work by clicking and filling in standard Windows buttons and forms, although there are probably other mechanisms as well.